# How to autoload and call an independent PHP class without using require_once?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

I have a main class called `EQ`, connected to other classes, and can be viewed in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/emarcier/usco/tree/master/master/cron/equity).

The EQ class is not connected to my [composer](https://github.com/emarcier/usco), and I call it in local server using:

```
php -f path/to/EQ.php
```

and live server using a CRON job:

```
1,15,30,45  *   *   *   *   (sleep 12; /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/EQ.php >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

I'm not sure how to correctly use an autoloader and load all dependent files to this class, and remove `require_once`s. I have tried and it does seem to be working:

```
spl_autoload_register(array('EQ', 'autoload'));
```

How do I solve this problem?

#### Attempt

```
//Creates a JSON for all equities // iextrading API
require_once __DIR__ . "/EquityRecords.php";
// Gets data from sectors  // iextrading API
require_once __DIR__ . "/SectorMovers.php";
// Basic Statistical Methods
require_once __DIR__ . "/ST.php";
// HTML view PHP
require_once __DIR__ . "/BuildHTMLstringForEQ.php";
// Chart calculations
require_once __DIR__ . "/ChartEQ.php";
// Helper methods
require_once __DIR__ . "/HelperEQ.php";

if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
} else {
    error_reporting(0);
}

/**
 * This is the main method of this class.
 * Collects/Processes/Writes on ~8K-10K MD files (meta tags and HTML) for equities extracted from API 1 at iextrading
 * Updates all equities files in the front symbol directory at $dir
 */

EQ::getEquilibriums(new EQ());

/**
 * This is a key class for processing all equities including two other classes
 * Stock
 */
class EQ
{



}

spl_autoload_register(array('EQ', 'autoload'));
```

Comment: You should [read the manual about auto loading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), It has several examples. You can also google on _"php psr-4 autoloader"_. Or you could simply let composer autoload your classes.

Comment: You said `spl_autoload_register(array('EQ', 'autoload'));` "does seem to be working" so what is the problem?

Comment: All that's needed is to put the logic in your autoload function for mapping class names to file locations. When your code calls `new Something` it passes the class name as a string `Something`; you have to figure out where it is and then include (or require) it.

Comment: Not sure that you have stated a problem but if needed check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially your autoloader function maps a class name to a file name. For example:

```
class EQ
{
    public function autoloader($classname)
    {
        $filename = __DIR__ . "/includes/$classname.class.php";
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            require_once $filename;
        } else {
            throw new Exception(sprintf("File %s not found!", $filename));
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(["EQ", "autoloader"]);

$st = new ST;
// ST.php should be loaded automatically
$st->doStuff();
```

But, most of this stuff is built into PHP, making your code even simpler:

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();
$st = new ST;
$st->doStuff();
```

As long as `ST.php` is anywhere in your `include_path` it just works. No autoloader function needed.